# automatic export csv file from Tableau to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, tableau-api

I would like to export my Tableau report to excel file and save it in S3.
Everything should be done automatically via scheduler
Somebody implemented it?
Thanks Alla

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the csv/excel file from a tableau dashboard:

Follow this link: https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/blog/2014/04/exporting-csv-made-simple.

1 - Add a URL action to your dashboard.
2 - Take the URL of the dashboard and add it in the URL action.
3 - Extend the URL with .csv extension.

Once you have the file, you'd have to write a custom script to take the from the foler (preferablly a folder on a network drive) and upload to S3.

Follow this link to do that: https://medium.com/@ricardoandreotte/guide-how-to-transfer-files-from-a-directory-on-the-network-to-s3-on-aws-6ff37d070dbe.

Hope this helps!